# What is the expected remaining life duration of a cell in the $t\to\infty$ limit?

Tags: stochastic-processes, mathematical-biology

Consider the following population model: We start with a population of a single cell at time $t=0$. Each cell divides into $k$ new cells at random times $T$ distributed according to a probability density function $f(T)$. We now wait for a long time and pick a random cell in the current population. Assuming we are in the $t\to \infty$ regime, what will be the average remaining time before division?

For the case $k=1$, this is a renewal process and I believe that the average remaining time will be $\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[T^2\right]}{2\mathbb{E}\left[T\right]}$. However I am unsure how to extend it for $k>1$. Ideally, I would like to express it in terms of a large deviation principle but my textbooks (e.g. Karlin and Taylor, Athreya, Harris) do not cover this case (I think!). An exact reference or just a brief derivation would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree.   I think the exponential growth biases it towards younger individuals, that is, lots of newborns. My back of the envelope calculation is the following.  Suppose the distribution of birth times is 1 with prob 1/2 and 2 otherwise, so everything happens at times 1,2 etc.  Then I think that over time the population will be 2/3 either newborns or those who have just given birth, and 1/3  those who are a year away from birth.  This is because calling $a_n$ the proportion of the former,  and $b_n$ the latter,  $a_{n+1} = b_n + \frac 12 a_n$. If proportions are going to converge, so $b_n \approx \alpha n$ then $\alpha = \frac 13$.  Then you can can calculate that a randomly chosen individual will have expected time $\frac 13  + \frac 23 \times \frac 32 = \frac 43$  whereas $\frac {ET}{2ET^2} = \frac 3 {10}$.

Comment: What do you not agree with? when $k=1$ the population is constant: it is only a single individual at all times.  Each cell divides into $k$ offsprings only once. The case $k=1$ is simply described by a renewal process and the expected remaining time really is $ET/(2ET^2)$. For $k>1$ there is indeed an exponential growth and the result from renewal theory does no apply. In a nutshell, I posted here exactly because the formula I give does not hold...